Multiple data validations on one cell
I have two cells, A1 & B1. If user selects Yes, Maybe in A1, B1 should be enabled (should accept value). I was able to do this via =OR($A$1='Yes',$A$1='Maybe')
The challenge is B1 is also a dropdown cell. Which means it already has a list validation added to it. Any way I can combine to two to enable/disable dropdown based on value selected? I can't use VBA as this workbook could be shared through email.

What kind of value do you want in B1, is it from a selected list, or can it be any data? It's a bit important to clean up my answer.

When you mean enabled I guess you are refering enabled/disabled features. If you need to lock/unlock the cell in real time based on the value of another cell you'll need VBA for that.


This is what my starting data looks like, I have 4 named ranges:
The headers, which I named 'CheckOne', then each row, without the headers; named 'YES', 'MAYBE' and 'NO';
Make your first validation list in A1, using 'CheckOne'; then make the second list, but in the source you put =INDIRECT(A1).
If your first list is not selected yet, you'll be prompted with an error, just skip that.

Right, one more crucial step, check off or change your error message (last tab in the setup popup window). It won't be dependant on whether A1 or B1 have the right value though.

Note: you can leave out the '0' on the no-list, and you'd get an empty return.
You can also double name one range, just select it twice and put in a different name, or use the name manager.
I might have missed a bit of the question, hope it still helps.

Are helper columns allowed? You could make a dynamic list somewhere dependent on A1 value and refer to in in B1 data validation.
Data validation "List" in A1:
=$D$1:$D$3

Formula in F1:
=IF(A1="Yes",E1:E5,"")

Data validation "List" in B1:
=F1#

You can hide those helper columns if needed.
Result with "Yes":

Result with "No":

